# Testing ng-repeat filter expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

I have a following ng-repeat expression

```
ng-repeat="a in result.data | orderBy:'x':true | limitTo:20"
```

I want to test if elements are sorted and if there are only 20 shown. First step would be to mock httpBackend request and return, say, 21 elements, then check order and count. What's the best way to do it? Do I need to engage browser (e2e test)?

EDIT: Let me clarify. I know I can use protractor and selenium to test it, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something like [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor).

Comment: I have set up protractor for other e2e tests. My questions is do I need the browser?